# paintComponent overwrites pixels

Tags: java

So I've added a grid to my BufferedImage, by doing it in the `PaintComponent`like this. It works perfect.

```java
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Color c=new Color(184, 184, 184, 255);
    g.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, this);
    for ( int x = 0; x <= getWidth(); x += 10 ){
        for ( int y = 0; y <= getHeight(); y += 10 ){
            g.setColor(c);
            g.drawRect( x, y, 10, 10 );
        }
    }
}
```

BUT, when I then draw my line/circles in this function:

```java
public void drawPixels(Object val_x, Boolean highlight)
{
    String[] values = val_x.toString().replaceAll("[()]", "").split(",");
    if (highlight){
        canvas.setRGB(Integer.parseInt(values[0]), Integer.parseInt(values[1]), Color.RED.getRGB());
    }else{
        canvas.setRGB(Integer.parseInt(values[0]), Integer.parseInt(values[1]), c.getRGB());
    }
    repaint();
}
```

I see that some of my pixels is overwriten by the grid from `paintComponent`.

Is there a way to z-index the grid behind the pixels I draw, or maybe draw the grid first, and then draw on the top of that?

My GUI looks like this, where you can see that my circles pixels is swapped with the grid:

[image]

**If you want to look at the whole drawing .java file**

```java
package DrawCanvas;

import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.Bool;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {
    private                 BufferedImage canvas;
    private static          Graphics g2;
    final private           Color c         = Color.BLACK;
    private final static    Color def_bg    = new Color(108, 108, 108, 255);
    //private final static    Color def_bg    = new Color(80, 80, 80, 255);
    int                     width           = 1280;
    int                     height          = 720;
    public DrawCanvas() {
        canvas = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        g2 = canvas.getGraphics();
        fillCanvas(def_bg);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Color c=new Color(184, 184, 184, 255);
        g.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, this);
        for ( int x = 0; x <= getWidth(); x += 10 ){
            for ( int y = 0; y <= getHeight(); y += 10 ){
                g.setColor(c);
                g.drawRect( x, y, 10, 10 );
            }
        }
    }

    public void fillCanvas(Color c) {
        int color = c.getRGB();
        for (int x = 0; x < canvas.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < canvas.getHeight(); y++) {
                canvas.setRGB(x, y, color);
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }


    // Implementation from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#All_cases
    public void drawPixels(Object val_x, Boolean highlight)
    {
        String[] values = val_x.toString().replaceAll("[()]", "").split(",");
        if (highlight){
            canvas.setRGB(Integer.parseInt(values[0]), Integer.parseInt(values[1]), Color.RED.getRGB());
        }else{
            canvas.setRGB(Integer.parseInt(values[0]), Integer.parseInt(values[1]), c.getRGB());
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void clearImage() {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) canvas.getGraphics();
        g2.setBackground(def_bg);
        g2.clearRect(0,0, (int)canvas.getWidth(), (int)canvas.getHeight());
        repaint();
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1 solution**

```java
package DrawCanvas;

import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.Bool;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {
    private                 BufferedImage canvas;
    private static          Graphics g2;
    final private           Color c         = Color.BLACK;
    private final static    Color def_bg    = new Color(108, 108, 108, 255);
    private final static    Color grid      = new Color(149, 149, 149, 186);
    //private final static    Color def_bg    = new Color(80, 80, 80, 255);
    int                     width           = 1280;
    int                     height          = 720;
    public DrawCanvas() {
        canvas = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        g2 = canvas.getGraphics();
        fillCanvas(def_bg);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void fillCanvas(Color c) {
        int color = c.getRGB();
        for (int x = 0; x < canvas.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < canvas.getHeight(); y++) {
                canvas.setRGB(x, y, color);
            }
        }
        drawGrid();
        repaint();
    }


    // Implementation from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#All_cases
    // Implementation from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#All_cases
    public void drawPixels(Object val_x, Boolean highlight)
    {
        Graphics2D graph = canvas.createGraphics();
        String[] values = val_x.toString().replaceAll("[()]", "").split(",");
        if (highlight){
            graph.setColor(Color.RED);
            graph.drawOval(Integer.parseInt(values[0]), Integer.parseInt(values[1]), 1, 1);
        }else{
            graph.setColor(c);
            graph.drawOval(Integer.parseInt(values[0]), Integer.parseInt(values[1]), 1, 1);
        }
    }

    public void drawGrid(){
        Graphics2D graph = canvas.createGraphics();
        for (int x = 0; x < canvas.getWidth(); x += 10) {
            for (int y = 0; y < canvas.getHeight(); y += 10) {
                graph.setColor(grid);
                graph.drawRect( x, y, 10, 10 );
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void clearImage() {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) canvas.getGraphics();
        g2.setBackground(def_bg);
        g2.clearRect(0,0, (int)canvas.getWidth(), (int)canvas.getHeight());
        drawGrid();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, if you paint multiple geographic figures on a drawing JPanel with the paintComponent method, the figures are drawn in the order you draw them.  If you want a grid to overlay your drawing, draw the grid last.

Comment: okay, thought i had to draw it first...

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Can't make it work though? have a suggestion on how?

Comment: In your DrawCanvas class, you draw on a BufferedImage, then paint the BufferedImage in your paintComponent method.  Why?  You can paint directly on the drawing JPanel using the paintComponent method.  Draw in the order you want the various geometric shapes to appear on your drawing JPanel.

Comment: made it work :) I can post my solution, so you can see if it's what you wanted, but i does it right